# Handle a space inside a php query in PHP

Tags: php

I'm using a file get contents to show the last news of a page. Some of my page titles have more than one word. How can i work with this spaces between the words. `Title` works. `Second title` isn't working at the moment. Thanks for your support.

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/archiv?s='.$t['page.content_title'].''); ?>
```

Comment: check `urlencode` method [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

Comment: ah cool. thanks. can you help to include this inside the url of my question? only this word and ()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
<?php 
echo file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/archiv?s='. urlencode($t['page.content_title'])); 
?>
```

Comment: @peer like this.

Comment: thank you very much!